# Using kafka stream state store to hold over 500 million message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to evaluate if kafka stream with rocksdb state store and be used in production with 500 million message in the changelog (state topic).

Use case
I have about 8 different topic's data I about, that are owned by different teams, from the these topic I care about certain data point, so I am using rocksdb to hold the state of the object, to which I add the required data from different topic.

Has kafka stream with state store being used this way ?

Comment: The cardinality of the keyset is more important than the total volume of messages. For example, if you have one unique key, and 500 billion messages with that same key, then it's only compacted to store one record.

Comment: what if there are 500 million different keys, and updates to those 500 million keys come in at random time ?

Comment: Time doesn't matter either. If you want to store every unique entry, then you'll need lots of disk space to store the RocksDB database

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the State store to store millions of keys. It requires the disk storage to store all the entries as @cricket007 also mentioned. As states are flushed to the file system. 
Usually millions of keys causes the storage or memory issues. As long as you have storage available, it will work.Also, you need to make sure that states are not in memory.

On a personal experience, I have around 100 millions of keys in several state stores, I ran into disk space problem first but after adding more disks, it works fine.

Also, you can read more about Capacity planning to get some fair idea : 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html